# What item in Windows 10 regional settings controls the interpretation of Excel TEXT() parameter 2

Tags: excel, formatting, regional-settings

I live in Holland, but my copy of Windows is English, not Dutch, and my regional settings specify decimal points not commas, list separator commas not semicolons, etc. My copy of MS Office is also English not Dutch. I know this is true because I had to buy the Dutch spell checker separately: only English, French and German were included.

Following a recent Windows Update (March or April, I think), my copy of Excel  started expecting Dutch-language format strings. So before, if I had a formula

```
=TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

I would see `2018-05-20`. After the change, this formula yields `yyyy-05-20` and the only way to get it to work is to change the formula to

```
=TEXT(TODAY(), "jjjj-mm-dd")
```

The same change affected custom number formatting in Excel, in the dialogue box `Format Cells | Number | Custom`.

My question is, which *particular* setting in Regional Settings or which *particular* registry key controls this behaviour? I've already tried everything I can think of, so answers of the form *change it in Regional Settings* will not be helpful. The settings I have are

```
Region & language
Country or Region:         United Kingdom
Windows display language:  English (United Kingdom)
Preferred languages:
    English (United Kingdom) - Windows display language
    English (United States) - Language pack installed
Date & time
Time zone: (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome Stockholm, Vienna
Formats
First day of week:     Monday
Short date:            2018-05-20
Long date:             Sunday 20 May 2018
Short time:            23:43
Long time:             23:43:46

Change date and time formats
Short date:            dd/MM/yyyy
Long date:             dddd, d MMMM yyyy
Short time:            HH:mm
Long time:             HH:mm:ss
```

Note particularly that Windows regional settings offer me `yyyy` and `HH` but Excel insists on `jjjj` and `uu`.

[image: Excel Custom number formatting dialogue]

And my Office Language Preferences don't mention Dutch anywhere, except as *Not installed*:

[image: Office Language Preferences]

I suspect this is a magic registry setting but intermittent googling over a period of 6 weeks or more hasn't yielded anything usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of different places where the locale is mentioned.  I believe the one you need to change, for the `daycode`, `monthcode` and `yearcode`  settings in Excel, is on the Region dialog box Formats tab.  Change the Format entry to the country/language of choice.

[image]

Comment: That was it. Thank you. It was set to English (Netherlands).

Comment: @BoarGules Glad to help.  I edited my response for a more precise explanation of what is being affected here, for others that might look at this in the future.